# Configure UDDI 3 to resolve SAP Endpoint in BizTalk ESB

Tags: biztalk, esb, uddi

I am looking a tutorial or step wise document that explains how to create and configure UDDI 3 to resolve SAP and SQL endpoints in BizTalk ESB solution.

My scenario is i need to send a request to SAP and receive response dynamically based on Content message type.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: UDDI 3 is also deprecated. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84c01d4d-aba9-4e6e-a693-63095c8d3ce1/uddi-30-deprecated?forum=biztalkgeneral

Answer (score 2):

**HOLD ON!  Do not even try to use UDDI.**

UDDI has been deprecated in the BizTalk Product and beyond that, no one, literally, every used it.  No one, ever.

Comment: And not only deprecated but actually removed altogether in BizTalk 2016  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt670742.aspx   Wouldn't say never used at all, one developer I know mentioned that he used UDDI in some SQL connections strings in maps

Answer (score 0):

For Sql adapter, you can refer to post at http://geekswithblogs.net/paulp/archive/2011/09/28/147087.aspx

Once you have SQL adapter working with STATIC resolver, simply use resolver connection string from itinerary XML to populate same key value pairs in UDDI. Next test resolver on designer surface to ensure that you are getting same name value pairs. Yes, UDDI 3 is unfortunately deprecated, so you may consider either BRE or implement SQL resolver.